# Why is my program having troubles connecting to Arduino's bluetooth module using .connect()?

Tags: android, sockets, bluetooth

I’m currently struggling with implementing a bluetooth communictation between an Arduino (HC-06 bluetooth module) and an Android mobile phone. I’ve created a number of textView.setText(…) commands in order to follow how the program reacts when running. 
My ambition for now is to get some primitive data from the Arduino (some characters only), and at the moment of the aquisition some reaction should happen on the screen (like a textView changes). That’s what I was trying to implement in my code below.

At the current state I’m having the following problems:

1. Sometimes mmSocket.connect(); is run properly and the otherwise constantly blinking red LED on the Arduino Bluetooth module starts shining, indicating that connection is established between the two devices. This is quite random though, usually this is not the case. Instead, I get a "Socket closed due to connect exception." answer, i.e. the try{} block isn’t run for some reason.
2. When, accidentally, connection is established, the red LED is shining, I don’t see anything on the screen of my phone. Normally it is supposed to output 4 textViews, each of them providing information about different parts of the code. How can I get it react real-time? It seems the .connect() makes the program halt around that point, although I don’t understand why.

I would appreciate any kind of help, I’m pretty new to this.

```
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.UUID;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
private BluetoothDevice mDevice;
private ConnectThread mConnectThread;
private Thread workerThread;
private String MAC = "30:14:10:17:06:93";
private boolean stopWorker;
private int readBufferPosition;
private byte readBuffer[];


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TextView supportsBTorNot = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.supportsBTorNot);
    TextView listPairedDevices = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.listPairedDevices);

    mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
        supportsBTorNot.setText("The device does not support bluetooth.");
    }
    else{
        if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, 1);
        }
        else{
            supportsBTorNot.setText("The device supports bluetooth.");
        }
    }

    Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
    listPairedDevices.setText(pairedDevices.toString());
    if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
        for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
            if(device.getAddress().equals(MAC)) {
                mDevice = device;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if (mDevice == null) {
        //Device is not paired yet
        //Need to initiate a connection request
    }

    mConnectThread = new ConnectThread(mDevice);
    mConnectThread.start();
}


private class ConnectThread extends Thread {

    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private ConnectedThread mConnectedThread;
    private final UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");

    TextView socketConnected = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.socketConnected);

    public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device) {
        BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
        try {
            tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            socketConnected.setText("Socket's create() method failed");
        }
        mmSocket = tmp;
        run();                                                                                          }

    public void run() {
        mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

        try {
            mmSocket.connect();                                                                             } catch (IOException connectException) {                                                                socketConnected.setText("Socket closed due to connect exception."); 
            try {                                                                                                   mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException closeException) {
                socketConnected.setText("Could not close the client socket.");
            }
            return;
        }
        if (mmSocket.toString() != null) {
            socketConnected.setText("The socket is established successfully.");
        }
        else {
            socketConnected.setText("The socket could not be stablished.");
        }

        mConnectedThread = new ConnectedThread(mmSocket);
        mConnectedThread.start();
    }

    public void cancel() {
        try {
            mmSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            socketConnected.setText("Could not close the client socket.");
        }
    }
}


private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private final OutputStream mmOutStream;
    TextView socketReadyForDataAquisition = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.socketReadyForDataAquisition);

    public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {

        mmSocket = socket;
        InputStream tmpIn = null;

        try {
            socketReadyForDataAquisition.setText("Querying the input stream has started.");
            tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            socketReadyForDataAquisition.setText("Querying of input suspended due to IOException!");
        }

        beginListenForData(tmpIn);
    }

    public void beginListenForData(InputStream iStream)
    {
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        final InputStream mmInputStream = iStream;

        stopWorker = false;
        readBufferPosition = 0;
        readBuffer = new byte[1024];

        workerThread = new Thread(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() && !stopWorker)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        int bytesAvailable = mmInputStream.available();
                        if(bytesAvailable > 0)
                        {
                            final byte[] packetBytes = new byte[bytesAvailable];
                            mmInputStream.read(packetBytes);
                            if(packetBytes != null) {
                                socketReadyForDataAquisition.setText("DATA ARRIVED");
                            }
                        }


                    }
                    catch (IOException ex)
                    {
                        stopWorker = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        workerThread.start();


    }

    public void write(byte[] bytes) {
        try {
            mmOutStream.write(bytes);
        } catch (IOException e) { }
    }

    public void cancel() {
        try{
            mmSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) { }
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Generally looking over your code nothing plainly pops out, but reading though your issue it seems that perhaps the Arduino does not close its socket even though you think you have disconnected the phone from it. I am no expert in Arduino so that is more of a general suggestion to look into as I had a similar problem working with a Raspberry Pi and connecting it to an android phone.

Specifically for your Android code, I would recommend to look into this guide:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html

If you plan on sending something back from the Arduino to the Phone you should consider setting up the phone as both a server and a client so it can send as well as receive data.

The developer guide is very useful and may help you see an issue. Additionally you may consider updating UI in its own thread as I have seen that also cause issues.

I am fairly new to Android Development, however, I have had to work with BT and that guide was a life saver.

Comment: Dear Andrei, thank you for your answer! I'll look these up.
What do you mean exactly by "the Arduino does not close its socket even though you think you have disconnected the phone from it"? Should I close the socket at the beginning of Arduino code, so that the program starts with a default deconnection each time it is run? 

"If you plan on sending something back from the Arduino to the Phone" Actually this is what I'm trying to implement. The Arduino sends the data, and the Android Phone receives it. Is it correct?

Comment: What I am talking about is if for example you were testing your connection with the phone and then turned off the phone application, there is a possibility that you have coded your Arduino code incorrectly and the socket continues to stay open and thinks that it is still connected to the phone. Therefore, I would recommend to double check your code in Arduino to make sure that if a connection is disconnected the program acknowledges that. For Raspberry Pi I had multiple sockets to deal with, thus I would try to connect to socket 1, but the Raspberry Pi was listening on socket 2.

Comment: I see. Well, in Arduino code I don't think I'm supposed to set sockets, since the phone connects itself to the Arduino's bluetooth module. And if connection is established, Arduino starts sending the data. In code:   

if (mySerial.available()) {
    mySerial.write('a'); //or any other chars, doesn't matter
}

Comment: Can you connect more than one device at a time to the Arduino module?